# Trigger event before pushstate changes

Tags: javascript, html, pushstate, html5-history

I need to update the pushstate of window.history before it changes, for example when I click the back button the pushstate changes, but I need to add something to it before that happens, and the only way to do that seems to be an event that fires before the pushstate changes, does this exist?

Comment: Take a look at the [WindowEventHandlers.onpopstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate). In case of a browser back button click this event will get fired.

Comment: Yes but I think that fires after the pushstate has already changed, which is too late for me to do the changes, I need it to be triggered before it happens.